# read / write mp4 id3 tags with PHP

Tags: php, mp4, id3, read-write, id3-tag

I need to be able to at very least read and preferably write id3 tags connected to an mp4 video file.

I've looked into using getId3() but it's got so many functions that finding those applicable to mp4 video files is difficult and the write demo files don't work on mp4 files

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what platform are you using?  Windows?  Linux?  Is it possible to execute outside software?

Comment: on a mac, the tags are definitely there. used several different programs to test this

Comment: that's not what I was getting at.  I was going to suggest using an external program to read the tags.  There is a handy library called taglib for doing just that, from many, many different file formats.  I don't know what languages you know, but if you could use that library, you're set.  I'm doing the same thing right now with a .NET application that loads the file tags into a database, for later consumption by a PHP web application.

Comment: ill have a look at that but what i'm really looking for is simplicity. Trying to cut out steps in storing large amounts of video and have the meta tags as a fall back if the database is lost

Comment: of course, and I hope you find that simple answer.  I'm just suggesting that there may not be a simpler solution than getting the tags externally.

Answer (score 2):

ID3 tags, as such, are only generally used on MP3 streams. I believe that MPEG 4 uses its own metadata format (within the `meta` atom). For details, see http://atomicparsley.sourceforge.net/mpeg-4files.html.

Comment: ID3 tags can most definitely be used for other file types.  It's just that they often aren't.  Saying that ID3 is only applicable to MP3 streams is absolutely false.

Comment: i managed to pull the artist tag from an mp4 file using the simple.demo.php demo file in getId3() but that's all i can manage

Comment: @Brad: Fixed the wording. It's at least probably true that most tools only expect ID3 tags to be on MP3 files.